# What is Lovecraftesque?

Tags: system-introduction, lovecraftesque

I was looking at [another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79744/can-lovecraftesque-do-one-room-horror) that was asking a question about Lovecraftesque, and it looked really cool, but what actually is it?

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to take this question as an opportunity to give you my sales pitch, but let me lead off by saying that following a [successful kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1122788890/lovecraftesque) the game is in layout, and we're expecting to release it in the second half of 2016.

- [*Lovecraftesque*](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1122788890/lovecraftesque) is a GMless game of creeping cosmic horror for 2-5 people.
- The game lets you create your own eldritch monstrosities and apocalyptic revelations with the help of your friends. You will build a story that feels like Lovecraft could have written it, one clue at a time.
- Like Lovecraft's own stories, the game focuses on a single Witness who stumbles upon something terrifying and has their worldview blown apart. They gradually uncover a horrifying secret before undergoing a journey into darkness and encountering a monstrous creature or finally comprehending an awful, worldview-shattering truth.
- Each turn of the game, one of you will act as Narrator and introduce some kind of strange clue. One of you will play the Witness. Any other players will be Watchers who provide extra atmospheric detail, play secondary NPCs and suchlike.
- After each turn, you leap to conclusions about what the horror is based on the clues so far. Then you rotate roles and go again.
- After around 6-8 clues, the game suddenly accelerates as the Witness enters the Journey into Darkness, culminating in a terrifying conclusion that one of you will weave using the conclusions they've leaped to. (That might sound hard, but trust me, there's always someone - usually several someones - who have a great idea for an ending.)
- As gatherer818 said, we've made a real effort to keep the game free of Lovecraft's racist ideas, and his odd ideas about mental illness. There are tools in the game to help you make the game feel Lovecraftian without duplicating his bigotry.

There's loads more information on the kickstarter page, of course.